# What is the file to be specified in guix system reconfigure?

Tags: guix, guixsd

The [documentation](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Invoking-guix-system.html) for `guix system reconfigure` says:

> Build the operating system described in *file*, activate it, and switch to it.

A cursory search didn't bring up any information on what or where that *file* is or how to generate it.

As @muru commented, that page also says:

> Once you have written an operating system declaration as seen in the previous section

...but that section is [Bootloader Configuration](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Bootloader-Configuration.html) and likewise does not tell me where to find that file on my system.

Since this step is part of a normal system upgrade (after runnnig `guix pull` as described in multiple places), I would've expected something a bit more obvious... but since I am a complete noob in GuixSD, I could easily be wrong.

Comment: It also says "*file* must be the name of a file containing an `operating-system` declaration", and "Once you have written an operating system declaration as seen in the previous section" at the top of the section.

Comment: @muru In the documentation I have linked to, the previous section is called [Bootloader Configuration](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Bootloader-Configuration.html#Bootloader-Configuration) and again, I couldn't see anything there on how to generate one. Given that this system is already running, I am kind of baffled I can't do the Guix equivalent of `sudo apt upgrade`... but again, as I said, I might be looking in completely the wrong place.

Comment: The "the" might be a mistake. They're probably referring to other sections in https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/System-Configuration.html#System-Configuration, such as https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/operating_002dsystem-Reference.html#operating_002dsystem-Reference, but in any case, it seems to me you *must* have had such a file in the first place, to have even started this system. Just re-use that.

Comment: @muru I'm sure that the file I'm looking for is *somewhere* on this machine. And now we're finally getting to the meat of my question: Where is it or how do I generate it? I simply followed the standard installation process [here](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/System-Installation.html), which may have told me where it generated that file but since this was months ago (this is a toy project for now), I can't remember and thought others might bump into the same problem when they come back and want to upgrade their system.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/After-System-Installation.html#After-System-Installation

Comment: @muru Thanks, I guess that's it! If you put that into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [3.7 After System Installation](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/After-System-Installation.html#After-System-Installation), it says:

> #### 3.7 After System Installation
>
> Success, you’ve now booted into Guix System! From then on, you can
>   update the system whenever you want by running, say:
>
> ```
> guix pull
> sudo guix system reconfigure /etc/config.scm
> ```

So `/etc/config.scm` might be what you're looking for.

And in [3.6.2 Proceeding with the Installation](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Proceeding-with-the-Installation.html#Proceeding-with-the-Installation):

> Next, you have to edit a file and provide the declaration of the
>   operating system to be installed. [...]. We strongly recommend storing
>   that file on the target root file system, say, as
>   `/mnt/etc/config.scm`. Failing to do that, you will have lost your
>   configuration file once you have rebooted into the newly-installed
>   system.
>
> See [Using the Configuration System](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Using-the-Configuration-System.html#Using-the-Configuration-System), for an overview of the
>   configuration file. The example configurations discussed in that
>   section are available under `/etc/configuration` in the installation
>   image. Thus, to get started with a system configuration providing a
>   graphical display server (a “desktop” system), you can run something
>   along these lines:
>
> ```
> # mkdir /mnt/etc
> # cp /etc/configuration/desktop.scm /mnt/etc/config.scm
> # nano /mnt/etc/config.scm
> ```

Which could tell you how you got that file in the first place.

Comment: Weird system.  In 2022, the 3.6.2 is still there in the current documentation, but(!) current install media offers a "graphical" install where you don't touch any file in an editor.  So… back to square one: how do I get `guix system` to write the current configuration into a file in my ~?

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard do you see anything in `/run/current-system/configuration.scm`?